# Installing Angular 4 on EC2 server

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2, angular-cli

My team is working on a Java EE, Oracle, and Angular 4 project, and we're trying to figure out how to install Angular 4 on our plain EC2 server. So far, I have googled and googled, and found no way to go about precisely this. How do I go about this?

**What I tried**

I said

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart
cd quickstart
npm install
```

on the BASH command line, which installed Angular 4. However, when I said `ng`, BASH told me: `-bash: ng: command not found`

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @estus I updated to include what I tried.

Comment: The procedure would likely be the same as on any other machine. You didn't install @angular/cli, did you? angular/quickstart is deprecated and doesn't support CLI, that's what repo page says. Are you trying to start a new project or set up existing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng` command is `angular-cli` command which is used to serve, test(unit, e2e), build and deploy angular project.

The error you are getting is not because of angular but angular cli. so first install `angular-cli` by below command in your EC2

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

Once its done, ng command will available in your server. But that is not the way to develop angular project.

You should follow below steps to develop and deploy your project.

- download the quick start or generate a project using `ng` command like `ng new proj-name` in your local machine
- Run `ng build` to build the project which will generate a `dist` folder and move that dis folder to your web server.

You can explore more options how to connect rest web services from your angular service and so on.

Comment: I just did that. It got stuck in installation loop of this: 

gyp verb command install [ '9.3.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "9.3.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 9.3.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 9.3.0
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_mod
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_m

Comment: might be you dont have permission to install in global scope as it will create ng command. if you build in your local you dont need `ng` command in ec2. so i would say build local and then just create a web server like tomcat and place your static content there

Comment: but I `^C`'d out of that. I then said `ng version` and it worked. However, I am now having trouble viewing the rendered content from the browser; /* I know it is on port 4200, and tried `[my IP]:4200`, but it results in a 404

Comment: You beat me by like 30 seconds

Comment: `ng serve` will serve the project inside ec2 with `http://localhost:4200`. so if you want to do that then inside your ec2 open a browser and try to run local host:4200. I am sure after get a quickstart project, inside your folder you are running `ng server` to serve it

Comment: Going back to your alternative suggestion, would I create this web server on my own machine or on EC2?

Comment: make it in your local machine and then build using `ng build` and then it will generate a `dist` folder with all the static code. then you just put that dist folder in your web server